# Better to create multiple related niche blogs or one blog that contains all related niches?

Tags: seo, domains, blog

I am finding it difficult to decide whether having small blog sites under specific domains is better than having one blog site that contains several sections about the subcategories of the main topic.

Let's say I am expert in cooking and want to write cooking lessons. I could buy some domains such as cookingdesserts.com, makejuices.com, veggiecooking.com and write about those specific subtopics which all relate to cooking.

Or is it better to find a domain that describes all those subtopics. For instance, cookingtutorials.com (assuming it is free) and then have menu items for each subtopic. If the user clicks on "Desserts" they are shown the blog articles about desserts.

It seems complicated to me to think and decide which method to use. I would appreciate knowing the pros and cons of each of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go with the one domain and rest of the topics as cateogries. By choosing this way, you can keep updating your site every day with new topic. The blog gets more content, more exposure to the other content as well.

As a SEO perspective, Having a one main domain and sub-topics as category is a really good idea. Since whenever you get a good backlinks from the press,sites etc the backlink juice passed to all the content.

So you work smarter here instead of working hard. You will have a huge community around the main topic and you can test and monetzie with different ways.

Other route:
Each topic as new site, then you need to work very hard to make it active. SEO has to be taken care of the each site and so the Social media promotions. Too many things. It's hard for the long run.

Go with the one domain idea only. Easy to handle and scale.

Hope this helps you. 
Good luck.

Comment: Perfectly said! I say this all the time- it is far easier to maintain one site than several. As well, if the topics are complimentary, you expand how your site is found and the potential that any user will stick around. Otherwise, tightly focused topic sites do not perform as well and are hard to maintain. Cheers!!